# Como faço para inserir uma nova linha entre outras duas linhas de uma tabela com jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, ajax, json

Bom dia! Tenho uma página com uma tabela, que é gerado pelo banco de dados. Preciso inserir uma nova linha através de um botão, porém, estou com dificuldade de inserir está nova linha entra outras duas linhas da tabela.Veja o código HTML abaixo para melhor entender:

```
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="json2.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.alphanumeric.pack.js"></script>
<script src="java.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="folha.css" />
</head>
<body>
<center><b><font size="5">AUTO PECAS TATETUBA LTDA - EPP</font></b></center>
<center><b><font size="4" color="#FF0000">PEDIDO DE COTAÇÃO</font></b></center><br>
<table id="dados">
<thead>
<tr>
<th id="td_titulo"></th>
<th>Descrição</th>
<th>Fabricante</th>
<th>Cód. Fabricante</th>
<th>Quantidade</th>
<th>Valor Unitário</th>
<th>Ações</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="dynamicRows">
<td class="pedido">3791</td>
<td>FITA DUPLA FACE PARA ESPELHO RETROVISOR</td>
<td>3M DO BRASIL LTDA</td>
<td>476</td>
<td>1</td>
<td><input type="text" name="11273" class="valor"/></td>
<td colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">
<button onclick="AddTableRow()" type="button">+</button>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="dynamicRows">
<td class="pedido">3792</td>
<td>INTERRUPTOR LUZ DE RE</td>
<td>3-RHO INTERRUPTORES AUTOMOTIVOS LTDA</td>
<td>4489</td>
<td>1</td>
<td><input type="text" name="493" class="valor"/></td>
<td colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">
<button onclick="AddTableRow()" type="button">+</button>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br><center><input type="button" class="Cenviar" value="Enviar" name="" id="00000186"/></center><br>
<div class="resultado"></div>
<br><center><b><font size="4" color="#FF0000">16/01/2018 09:50:09</font></b></center><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Código java:

```
(function($) {  
    AddTableRow = function() {
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";
    cols += '<td><input type="text"  size="34"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text"  size="34"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text"  class="valor"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text"  class="valor"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text"  class="valor"/></td>';
    cols += '<td>';
    cols += '<button onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">-</button>';
    cols += '</td>';
    $(newRow).append(cols);
    $("#dados").append(newRow);
    return false;
    };
})(jQuery);

(function($) {    
    RemoveTableRow = function(item) {       
        var tr = $(item).closest('tr'); 

        tr.fadeOut(400, function() {          
        tr.remove();        
      });   

    return false;     
    }   
})(jQuery);
```

Na forma como está, a linha é inserida no final da tabela, preciso que seja inserido entre duas linha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para inserir logo após a linha onde clicou no botão "+", precisa usar essa linha como referência e usar `insertAfter`, ou ainda `insertBefore` se quisesse antes:

```js
(function($) {  
    AddTableRow = function(btn) {
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";
    cols += '<td><input type="text"  size="34"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text"  size="34"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text"  class="valor"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text"  class="valor"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text"  class="valor"/></td>';
    cols += '<td>';
    cols += '<button onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">-</button>';
    cols += '</td>';
    $(newRow).append(cols);
    
    $(newRow).insertAfter($(btn).closest('tr'));
    
    //$("#dados").append(newRow);
    return false;
    };
})(jQuery);

(function($) {    
    RemoveTableRow = function(item) {       
        var tr = $(item).closest('tr'); 

        tr.fadeOut(400, function() {          
        tr.remove();        
      });   

    return false;     
    }   
})(jQuery);
```

```css
table {
  background-color: #aaa
}

table td {
  background-color: #fff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dados">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th id="td_titulo"></th>
         <th>Descrição</th>
         <th>Fabricante</th>
         <th>Cód. Fabricante</th>
         <th>Quantidade</th>
         <th>Valor Unitário</th>
         <th>Ações</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="dynamicRows">
         <td class="pedido">3791</td>
         <td>FITA DUPLA FACE PARA ESPELHO RETROVISOR</td>
         <td>3M DO BRASIL LTDA</td>
         <td>476</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="11273" class="valor"/></td>
         <td colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">
            <button onclick="AddTableRow(this)" type="button">+</button>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="dynamicRows">
         <td class="pedido">3792</td>
         <td>INTERRUPTOR LUZ DE RE</td>
         <td>3-RHO INTERRUPTORES AUTOMOTIVOS LTDA</td>
         <td>4489</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="493" class="valor"/></td>
         <td colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">
            <button onclick="AddTableRow(this)" type="button">+</button>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Note que pra ficar bem claro onde vai incluir, passei o botão como referência: `AddTableRow(this)`  e depois, a partir do botão, peguei a linha mais próxima: `.closest('tr')`

Comment: Muito obrigado Ricardo, salvou minha vida.